# Can the points be colored in the L'abbé-plot based on category in R metafor package?

Tags: r, plot, metafor

Is it possible to color the "points" in the L'abbé plot? I am using the metafor package.

```
 # Load package
 library(metafor)

 # Load data
 data(dat.bcg)

 # Code 
 ex <- rma(ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, 
 di=cneg, data=dat.bcg, measure="OR",
 slab=paste(author, year, sep=", "), method="FE")

# L'abbé plot
labbe(ex, transf = exp, ylab="Test group", xlab="Control")
```

Would it be possible to color the points based on a variable?

Fx blue colored points that represent:

```
dat.bcg$alloc==random
```

Thank you, C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
dat.bcg$var[dat.bcg$alloc == "random"] <- "blue"

labbe(ex, transf = exp, ylab = "Test group", xlab = "Control", bg = dat.bcg$var)
```

[image]

And without the transformation:

```
labbe(ex, ylab = "Test group", xlab = "Control", bg = dat.bcg$var, grid = TRUE)
```

[image]

We can see that there are 7 blue points for the 7 instances where `dat.bcg$alloc == "random"`.

Another option to distinguish between the points:

```
labbe(ex, ylab = "Test group", xlab = "Control", grid = TRUE, pch = dat.bcg$alloc)
```

[image]

To change the color of all three points you could do the following:

```
dat.bcg$var[dat.bcg$alloc == "random"] <- "blue"
dat.bcg$var[dat.bcg$alloc == "alternate"] <- "green"
dat.bcg$var[dat.bcg$alloc == "systematic"] <- "red"
```

Or with `dplyr` we can use `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)

dat.bcg <- dat.bcg %>% 
  mutate(var = case_when(alloc == "random" ~ "blue",
                         alloc == "alternate" ~ "green",
                         alloc == "systematic" ~ "red",
                         TRUE ~ as.character(NA)))
```

[image]

Comment: What if I want to add another color to dat.bcg$alloc=="alternate" (green) next to the blue ones?

Comment: You could do the following: `dat.bcg$var[dat.bcg$alloc == "alternate"] <- "green"`

Comment: This did not work: q1$var[q$alloc == "random"] <- "blue"
q1$var1[q$alloc == "alternative"] <- "green"
labbe(q1, transf = exp, ylab = "Test group", xlab = "Control", bg = dat.bcg$var, bg=dat.bcg$var1)

Comment: See my updated answer. Two things: only create one variable containing the colors (`var`) no need to make `var1`. Your colors probably aren't showing because you assign the `var` column to `q1` based on conditions in `q` not `dat.bcg` (which you're using for the `bg` argument).

Comment: Can I use RGB-colors?

Comment: I just noticed that the `bg` argument is not put in the correct order inside of the `labbe()` function. This has been fixed in the devel version. Make sure you install this before you make use of this answer. See here: https://github.com/wviechtb/metafor#installation